# How to add in proper vim `help word` so I can open the help section with K

Tags: vim

I am trying to add links for the places in my `vimrc` with the relevant help section, so I can press `K` on the word and open that. However, for something like this:

```
:h c_CTRL-R
```

To get information on inserting the contents of a register, if I put the cursor on the c:

```
:h |c_CTRL-R
```

And press `K`, it doesn't open the 'full word', and instead opens the help section for:

[image]

(probably the first item under `c_CTRL`). Is there a special way to annotate the text or something so that vim can recognize which help section to go to from pressing K? Currently I am doing `viWK`, so `:nnoremap K vaWK`.

**Update:** I ended up adding in the following mapping:

```
" K opens that item in the help section. Get whole word, minus any assignment (=)
:nnoremap K viWlF=hK
```

Comment: Does wrapping the WORD in asterisks help?

Comment: @L3viathan no, not for me.

Comment: You could set iskeyword to include hyphens, maybe